# Buttons in QListWidget not working (Using PyQt5)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I am a newbie in PyQt5 and learning to use QListWidget in a project. My problem is when I put three PushButtons inside a QListWidget. But when I click the buttons, nothing happened, and I cannot find the problem why.
So, could someone help me out? Thank you very much, and the following is my entire codes.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Main Window'
        self.left = 300
        self.top = 300
        self.width = 840
        self.height = 580
        self.Contents = QStackedWidget()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        # the following is to create a ToolBar  
        self.toolbar = QToolBar()
        self.toolbar.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(200, 155, 155);" 'spacing:20px;')
        self.toolbar.setFixedHeight(86)
        self.toolbar.setMovable( False)

        # create three pushbutton called Button1, Button2, Button3
        Button1 = QPushButton(self)
        Button1.setText("Home Button")


        Button2 = QPushButton(self)
        Button2.setText("Simulation")

        Button3 = QPushButton(self)
        Button3.setText("Practice")

        # create QListWidget and add the buttons into it
        self.itemN = QListWidgetItem() 
        self.funList = QListWidget()
        self.widget = QWidget()

        widgetLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        widgetLayout.addWidget(Button1)
        widgetLayout.addWidget(Button2)
        widgetLayout.addWidget(Button3)
        widgetLayout.addStretch()
        widgetLayout.setSizeConstraint(QLayout.SetFixedSize)
        self.widget.setLayout(widgetLayout) 

        self.funList.addItem(self.itemN)
        self.funList.setItemWidget(self.itemN, self.widget)
        self.funList.clicked.connect(self.clicked_check) # this click seems not working

        #put the QlistWidget into the toolbar
        self.toolbar.addWidget(self.widget)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        self.setLayout(vbox)      
        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def clicked_check(self):
        alert = QMessageBox()
        alert.setText('This Button works')
        alert.exec_()   

if not QApplication.instance():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
else:
    app = QApplication.instance()
ex = App()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Connect each button to the slot, rather than the list-widget. Use `self.sender()` inside the slot to find out which button was clicked.

Comment: Thanks Ekhumoro, the reason I tried to you QlistWidget is because after this, I need to apply QstackWidget, to open three smaller windows in the same area alternatively. Is there anything wrong with my logic? or I can do it in other ways?

Comment: @user1933836 per the documentation a QListWidget is made to hold only QListWidgetItems and QListWidgetItems are specific objects with specific properties these properties typically being Text and Icons where the Text is set with setText, and the Icon is set with setIcon -- from the documentation it appears that the QListWidget object is not meant to hold QPushButtons as you seem to imply you are trying to do.  So are you actually trying to put a QPushButton into a QListWidget?

Comment: @Dennis Jensen, Yes, I was trying to put a QPushButton into a QListWidget. So it seems I should not do this, right?

Comment: @user1933836 Yes, of course you ***can*** add other widgets to a list-widget - that's exactly what `setItemWidget` is for. Whether you actually need to in this particular case is unclear, though. Please edit your question and explain much more clearly what you are trying to achieve - your previous comments aren't making much sense.

Comment: The beauty and the curse of python and pyqt is that yes - you can do anything - but does that mean you should.  I mean you can build a castle in the swamp but you'd be daft to do so still it could be done.

Comment: That said I pointed out what the QListWidget documentation said about the QListWidget and I know for a fact that you can put QPushButtons into a QTreeView and from what I gather of the QListWidget is it is a sort of specialized version of the QTreeView scenario so when working with objects it is best to use them for what they were designed and drop back to a less specific version (in this case the QTreeView) to implement what you are trying to do.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand what you want to do, but if you put `self.funList` in the layout, we get the following result:

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Main Window'
        self.left = 300
        self.top = 100
        self.width = 840
        self.height = 380
        self.Contents = QStackedWidget()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        # the following is to create a ToolBar  
        self.toolbar = QToolBar()                                                        
        self.toolbar.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(200, 155, 155);" 'spacing:20px;')
        self.toolbar.setFixedHeight(86)
        self.toolbar.setMovable( False)

        # create three pushbutton called Button1, Button2, Button3
        Button1 = QPushButton(self)
        Button1.setText("Home Button")
        Button1.clicked.connect(lambda: print(Button1.text()))        # +

        Button2 = QPushButton(self)
        Button2.setText("Simulation")

        Button3 = QPushButton(self)
        Button3.setText("Practice")

        # create QListWidget and add the buttons into it
        self.itemN = QListWidgetItem() 

        self.funList = QListWidget()
        self.widget = QWidget()
#        self.widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 155, 000);")
#        self.funList.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 000, 155);")

        widgetLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        widgetLayout.addWidget(Button1)
        widgetLayout.addWidget(Button2)
        widgetLayout.addWidget(Button3)
        widgetLayout.addStretch()
        widgetLayout.setSizeConstraint(QLayout.SetFixedSize)
        self.widget.setLayout(widgetLayout) 

        self.funList.addItem(self.itemN)
        self.itemN.setSizeHint(self.widget.sizeHint())

        self.funList.setItemWidget(self.itemN, self.widget)
        self.funList.clicked.connect(self.clicked_check)      # this click seems not working

        #put the QlistWidget into the toolbar
        self.toolbar.addWidget(self.widget)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)

        vbox.addWidget(self.funList)                                            # <<<-----<

        vbox.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        self.setLayout(vbox)      
        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def clicked_check(self):
        alert = QMessageBox()
        alert.setText('This Button works')
        alert.exec_()   

if not QApplication.instance():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
else:
    app = QApplication.instance()
ex = App()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```